# Sails Waterline ORM query inside array.map()

Tags: javascript, async-await, sails.js, es6-promise, waterline

Code snippet below is using sails waterline ORM to make DB queries and sending response. However, the execution flow is weird, The code outside of map function is running before the map function has finished executing. 'I am outside of map' is being printed in the console before 'I am inside of map'. I think it can be solved this using Promise or async / await. I have tried using Promise.all() below, but it doesn't work, the response is always an empty array. I would be grateful if you could give an example on how to solve this kind of issues.

```
allMembers: (req, res) => {
  const projectId = req.params.id;

    ProjectMembers.find({projectId: projectId}).exec( (err, members) => {
        if(err) res.serverError("bad request!");

        if(members.length === 0) res.notFound({message: "No members are found for this project!"});

        let membersInfo = [];
        let promise = Promise.all(members.map(m => {
            User.findOne({id: m.userId}).exec( (err, user) => {
                if(err) membersInfo.push({name: null, userId: null, email:null,rate:null, error: 'Internal error!'})
                else if(!user) membersInfo.push({name: null, userId: null, email:null,rate:null, error: 'No user found'})
                else membersInfo.push({name: user.name, userId: user.id, rate: m.rate, error: null})
                console.log("i am inside of map");
            })
        }));

    console.log("I am outsie of map")
    promise.then( (resolve) => {return res.ok({members: membersInfo})});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was about to tell you "don't use queries in `.map`", but on looking, I think your code is quite close to working. The argument of `Promise.all` has to be an array of promises. Each `User.findOne` is indeed a promise - the stumbling block is that once you use `.exec` it no longer returns a promise.

I think the answer is to do your processing inside the `.then` instead of right inside the `.map`:

```
ProjectMembers.find({projectId: projectId}).exec( (err, members) => {
    if(err) return res.serverError("bad request!");

    if(members.length === 0) return res.notFound({message: "No members are found for this project!"});

    let promise = Promise.all(members.map(m => User.findOne({id: m.userId})));

    promise.then( (values) => {
        // values is the array of user objects returned from the array of queries
        let membersInfo = values.map((user) => {
            if (!user) {
                return {name: null, userId: null, email:null,rate:null, error: 'No user found'};
            } else {
                return {name: user.name, userId: user.id, rate: m.rate, error: null};
            }
        });
        return res.ok({members: membersInfo});
    }, (err) => {
        return res.serverError("Error finding users");
    });
```

The promise only has a single fail callback, so you lose the ability to *individually* catch and handle querying errors (though you can still individually handle not-found results).

Comment: Good. Depending on your db chosen, you could do one big `User.find` with OR criteria on the user ids instead of individual fondOnes.

Comment: @ManuelReil that's the approach I would have taken, and waterline could definitely do that with any underlying db. I was just trying to keep close to OP's logic which was reasonable and close to working.